# Counting people above 64 years with string

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas df has a column containg the birthyearof the household members and looks like this:

```
Birthyear_household_members
1960
1982 + 1989
1941
1951 + 1953
1990 + 1990
1992
```

I want to create a column with a variable that contains the number of people above 64 years old in a household.
Therefore, for each row, I need to separate the string and count the number of people with a birthyear before 1956.

How can I do this using pandas? My original df is very large.

Comment: You can probably use pandas.Series.str.split to turn the strings into a list of values. Then convert the split string values to numeric so you can do math on them to determine ages. Might need to include an explode to turn the lists into individual rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use apply method of your df

```
df['cnt'] = df['Birthyear_household_members'].apply(lambda x: len([None for year in x.split(" + ") if year < '1956']))
```

Comment: Although not a reasonable age for people if we had a birth year of 201 then this won't be counted.  Wouldn't it be better to use if `int(year) < 1956` to compare integers rather than strings to avoid issues of string comparison?

Comment: @DarrylG yes you are right. But if dataframe does not have data like that without conversion it will be faster